# "RCTImageView" was not found in the UIManager

Tags: react-native

I'm using `react-native` hybrid development, and I'm currently reporting errors on the IOS simulator

```
Invariant Violation:requireComponent:"RCTImageView" was not found in the UIManager
```

`RCTImage` was added to the Podfile file, but the pod install failed.

Comment: Can you give more detail about it maybe you should add some code sample. Also you can check here https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/22534

Comment: Better formatting

Comment: have you link plug in using react native

Answer (score 0):

If you're using cocoapods, you should check if the RCTImage is added in your Podfile.

[image]

Comment: If i am not using pod, is there any suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 0):

in case not using pod, check "Link Binary With Libraries" - should contains libRCTImage.a